# Defining NULL for an array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote a class in C++. In it I wrote:

```
class Node{
private:
Node*m[200]=NULL;
};
```

(This is a part of the class) But I receive errors. What should I do for defining an array of pointers, NULL ?

Comment: `NULL` is for pointers, not arrays. It makes no sense to initialize an array with `NULL`.

Comment: Try `Node* m[200]{};`. But even better, use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 6):

To make all 200 pointers be null, write:

```
class Node
{
    Node *m[200] = {};
};
```

This is only valid in C++11 and later.

Comment: Not sure if this was possible prior to C++11

Comment: 2.cpp:6:14: warning: non-static data member initializers only   available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
 Node*m[200]={};
                  ^
    2.cpp:6:14: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]

Comment: @AmirHavangi do as the error message says, and use `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

Comment: `{ 0 }` for pre-C++11.

Comment: @Pradhan I'm pretty sure that all inline braced-initializers are invalid before C++11 (your clang may be implementing an extension); what I meant was that I can't think of an alternative means of achieving the same initialization

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh duh! You were talking about braced-initializers for class members. Sorry, that wasn't what I was referring to.

Comment: @AmirHavangi read my earlier comment to fix your error. I think zenith overlooked that we were talking about a class member.

Comment: If you are using pre-C++11 then use a constructor to initialize the array: `class Node{ private:
Node* m[200]; public: Node() { std::fill(m, &m[200], 0); } };`.  You can use `std::fill_n()` instead of `std::fill()`: `std::fill_n(m, 200, 0);`

Comment: This is errors: required from ‘_OI std::fill_n(_OI, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _OI = Node**; _Size = Node**; _Tp = int]’
       2.cpp:44:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:751:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Node*’ [-fpermissive]
  *__first = __tmp;

Comment: @AmirHavangi change `0` to `(Node *)0` in that version. However this is much more complicated and unnecessary than my suggestion, seeing as you are using a compiler that does support C++11.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks! It was compiled correctly. But, my program has this error:  Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @AmirHavangi that error would be coming from a different part of your program. You could post a new question with your program (check [how to post code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first)

Comment: @RemyLebeau No need to call `std::fill`, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, if you don't have C++11 support, you can *value initialize* the array in a constructor. This has the effect of *zero initializing* the elements:

```
class Node
{
public:
  Node() : m() {}
private:
  Node* m[200];
};
```

Note also that value initializing instances of the original `Node` has the same effect WRT zero initializing the elements:

```
Node n = {}; // Node must be aggregate, as in original code.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're writing C++, I'd recommend avoiding raw arrays and using `std::vector` instead (or `std::array` if you have C++11).

In pre-C++11 you need initialize your members in the constructor:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node() : m(200) {}

private:
    std::vector<Node*> m;
};
```

This will initialize `m` to hold `200` null pointers when you construct a `Node`.